# How would one use System.Uri .NET class to check if the URL is valid?

Tags: .net, regex

In one of the [previous posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url) it was suggested to use System.Uri to check if the URL is valid.  How does one do that?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To check if an url is valid instead of using exceptions you can use the [TryCreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131572.aspx) method:

```
Uri result;
if (Uri.TryCreate("http://www.google.com", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out result)) 
{
    // the url is valid
}
```

Comment: Now according to Uri.TryCreate url such as hht://www.gogole.com is valid. Even though the htt: is invalid scheme. Why is htt: okay?

Comment: htt: is perfectly valid scheme. A custom protocol could define this scheme.

Comment: i tried this with an invalid Uri like this /folder/{ht.com.m\\/sx.r:erp://°? and returns true but the out parameter throws exceptions in every property, i guess the only way to truly test if the string represent an Uri is if the Uri is absolute

Comment: I think you should use "UriKind.Absolute". Also one need to consider that there is a difference between an "Uri" and "Url". I think you looking for the latter and this is not a great way to do it.

Comment: Maybe you are right, but then the contract for the method should be TryCreate(string, out Uri)) instead

Comment: I recommend use `UriKind.Absolute` instead `UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute`:

`
string uri = "zzzzz http://www.google.com.br/kkkkkkkkkkkk";
Uri.TryCreate(uri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out result)` <- `true`

`Uri.TryCreate(uri, UriKind.Absolute, out result)` <- `false`

Comment: I really doesn't understand why this bad answer has 29 upvotes. the Relative just checks for anything, and the Absolute just checks for the "http://" starting word, so RelaiveOrAbsolute just checks fon a not-empty string, and thats all, you can put a single character and that will be valid, so this is not a way to check it, is poor than a regex. very, very bad answer.

Comment: One more quirk to keep in mind is the change in System.URI ctor behavior in .NET version 4.5. See [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/10/17/net-framework-4-5-off-to-a-great-start/). Essentially: _In the .NET Framework 4.5, an invalid mailto: URL throws an exception in the Uri class constructor, to comply with the URI RFC_ (while it doesn't in .NET Framework 4 and below).

Answer (score 13):

Using Uri.TryCreate can have some problems with relative Uris, with string like this "/folder/{ht.com.m\/sx.r:erp://" TryCreate returns true, so i create this extension method using IsWellFormedUriString and TyrCreate, I'm not sure TryCreate is necessary, with my little tests i get the same results with or without TryCreate

```
public static bool IsUri(this string source) {
  if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(source) && Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(source, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)){
    Uri tempValue;
    return (Uri.TryCreate(source, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out tempValue));
  }
  return (false);
}
```

**Example**

```
address= "http://www.c$nbv.gob.mx"
if(address.IsUri()){
  //returns false
}
address= "http://www.cnbv.gob.mx"
if(address.IsUri()){
  //returns true
}
address= "http://www.cnbv.gob.mx:80"
if(address.IsUri()){
  //returns true
}
address= "/directory/path"
if(address.IsUri()){
  //returns true
}
address= "~re#l|ativ[ainco#recta\car:.\peta"
if(address.IsUri()){
  //returns false
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Can use the static IsWellFormedUriString method:

```
bool isValid = Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(url, UriKind.Absolute);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking to see if the structure of the URL is valid, then the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702144/how-would-one-use-system-uri-net-class-to-check-if-the-url-is-valid/702159#702159) is just fine.

However, if you want to check that the resource actually exists, you are going to have to use the classes that derive from WebRequest/WebResponse.  For HTTP and FTP resources, the HttpWebRequest/FtpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse/FtpWebResponse classes will work fine (as  will WebClient), but if you have other schemes that you have to support, you will have to find specific providers for that scheme.